# How can I remove class explorer at top of .java file?

Tags: eclipse

I have begun to see a type of class explorer at top of my .java file (beneath .java file name tab) in eclipse. Attached is a screen shot, I want to hide view behind the blue line.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button shown at the top left of your screenshot ...